# Can't save a python file in any IDE

Tags: python-3.x, save, geany

I'm currently starting to learn Python on Windows 10 and to do so I've installed Geany 1.34.1 and Python 3.7.2 (with the PATH option) as instructed in my book.

I then created a new file and tried to save it in some folder on my C: disk where both softwares are.

Unfortunately, I get the following error

[image: Error screenshot]

The translaton (original partly in french):

**"Error in saving the file. Failure to open the file "C:\Users\XXX\Documents\python_work\test.py" for writing: fopen() has failed: No such file or directory. The file on the disk may be truncated"**

I've tried with the Python IDLE as well and get the same problem where I can't save my file.

I've read that it could be due to the fact that in WIN we use \ and in Unix / but I really don't know why Geany can't do alone the translation.

After few hours of hit and miss, does anyone could explain the reason of this behaviour ?

Edit1: Transcription and translation of the error

Comment: Can you provide the error as text? Corporate proxies often block images (which is the case where I am), so there is zero error information in your question.  Text is easier to read, too. Always use text instead of images where possible.

Comment: @Ken White: i've edited the post accordingly. Thanks for your advice, I'll do so in the future.

Comment: May be related to this currently open bug: https://github.com/geany/geany/issues/1500

Comment: @davedwards thanks for the search. I've  already read it and I thought first it was only a Geany related problem but then I face unfortunately the same kind of error by saving with "IDLE" leading me to think that Geany is not fully responsible.

Comment: @endlessend2525, Can you save any simple text file to that `"python_work"` directory (e.g. `"afile.txt"` using a native Windows tool like Windows Notepad)? Seems like that directory `"\python_work\"` may have write permission restrictions. Possibly check the directories permissions in the folder properties.

Comment: Also can you create a new directory in a different location, e.g. on your User's Desktop `"C:\Users\XXX\Desktop"` and create a basic Text file (e.g. `"afile.txt"`) with Windows tools (Notepad, et. al.) there?

Comment: @daveedwards Just did both procedures and it didn't raise any error. I've checked as well the permission of the folder and there's no restriction on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

Make sure that the following is deactivated:

Windows Defender >  Virus & Threat protection > Virus & Threat protection settings option > Controlled folder access > Disabled

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because, in python and in other programming languages the "\" is used for some special character.
For ex. '\n' = new line
I'm not really sure, but I think it is for this reason, i had similiar problems at the begin.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've understood that as well but here i don't even write code. I just click on Save As and then choose a folder, give the name "test.py" and that's all.

Comment: The IDLE is giving you this error when you try to save an empty file named test.py, right?

Comment: The file is being saved in Geany or Idle, so what python or other programming languages use the backslash for is irrelevant. If it was the poster's code that was having problems, your answer might be relevant, but it isn't here.

Comment: @KenWhite yes I've thought so, so I've quickly ruled out this possibility. Well it's a shame that I really can't use python on my computer.